# How to control permission with views in sqlplus

Tags: sql, oracle, view, sqlplus

How can I create a single view that limits access to a table's contents for one user while limiting other users to a few columns.

For example:

Employers can view all data on all employees.

Employees can only view their own data. I.e. information about themselves.

All information is taken from a single table.

Edit.

I have a table that stores data on both employers and employees. I want to create a view where all data can be seen if  employer = true but if employees = true you can only view the row with their data.

Basically an IF ELSE statement

If employer =  true
show all
Else If employee = true 
show employee row.

Comment: You'd have to start by looking at how you decide if the user is an employer or an employee... You might be looking for [virtual private database](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/dbseg/using-oracle-vpd-to-control-data-access.html)?

Comment: Do you mean in SQL\*Plus specifically, or should this apply to all database access? If so, I'm not clear what the question has to do with SQL\*Plus.

Comment: Yes I need to implement this in SQL*Plus specifically.